# Passing ActionListener of a List of components in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I am very confused, many examples I have seen only deal with one button listener being passed. I want to be able to pass *ALL* Components of a View Class (JFrame) to the Controller Class which will have easy access to the listeners of those components. How Can I do this easily. This is what I've done so far with `JMenuItem`, but in the JFrame i have more buttons, dont want to repeat in the Constructor every time.

```
 public class EventController implements ActionListener {
    private EventModel model;
    private EventView view;



    public EventController(){
        model = new EventModel(); 

    }


    @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if (e.getActionCommand().equals("add")) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "add button clicked");
   }   else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("edit")) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "edit button clicked");
   }   else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("delete")) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "delete button clicked");
  }


    }
```

//class View

```
  public class EventView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn = JavaConnect.ConnectDB();
PreparedStatement pst = null; 
ResultSet rs = null; 


    public EventView() {
        initComponents();
        updateEventTable();
        addEvent.addActionListener(new EventController());
        addEvent.setActionCommand("add");
        editEvent.addActionListener(new EventController());
        editEvent.setActionCommand("edit");
        deleteEvent.addActionListener(new EventController());
        deleteEvent.setActionCommand("delete");
    }
    public void updateEventTable() {
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT date as 'Date',eventName as 'Name', time as 'Start Time' FROM Event";
             pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); 
             rs = pst.executeQuery();
             tableEvent.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
             tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
             tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(170);
             tableEvent.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(110);  
    }
        catch (Exception e ) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close(); pst.close();conn.close();;
            } catch(SQLException e){}
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method like this:

```
private void setListener(AbstractButton button, ActionListener listener, String command) {
  button.addActionListener(listener);
  button.setActionCommand(command);
}
```

Build a single `EventController` instance.

```
EventController controller = new EventController();
```

Then, call it for each button:

```
setListener(addEvent, controller, "add");
...
```

Comment: what if not just JButton, but a mix of MenuItem,Checkboxes etc.. Does argument JButton replace with component?

Comment: :D thanks, is repetition of setListener() in constructor of the View class for all buttons,menuitems (there are 6) a bad practice? 

also wanted to know how to pass control of view class initialisation to Controller class, so I avoid writing sql statements there, any idea?

Comment: You can keep them in a Collection and just iterate the collection and call the method.

Answer (score 2):

Create listener instance just once and reuse it. Like this

```
    EventController lst=new EventController();
    addEvent.addActionListener(lst);
    addEvent.setActionCommand("add");
    editEvent.addActionListener(lst);
    editEvent.setActionCommand("edit");
    deleteEvent.addActionListener(lst);
    deleteEvent.setActionCommand("delete");
```